# How do I set up web deploy in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net .
To publish the site it needs following inputs if I select web deploy.

Server: ...

Site path: .......

Username: ......

Password:......

Destination Url:......

My Hosting provider Provides me the following information :

Hostname srv031385

Primary IP 34.221.20.xx

Username:  Administrator

And... 
Address and port to connect via FTP 37.220.20.xx

Address to connect to the VNC Remote Console 34.220.20.xx

Port to connect to the VNC Remote Console 60085

The password for the VNC Remote Console: xxxxxxx

VPS number 85

**What do I fill in which columns please help.. 
** TO THE DOWNVOTERS: ****

It was not asked to avoid any efforts on my part.. the question is still open.

for example : Should I fill in the ipaddress:portnumber in the server field?

should I fill the same in site path as well? or should I fill mysubdomain.domain.com in the site path?

Or should I fill in mysubdomain.domain.com/myrootfolder in the site path?

And what is destination URL? It's just confusing. I referred to the folowing documentations but no help:

This official documentation, tells you nothing about how you deploy to your virtual private windows server :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: It is 2017, and Web Deploy is probably around for 10+ years. Your question looks to my like "Ah, don't wanna use that Google thing and don't wanna read through documentation, just help me, SO crowd".

Comment: @Uwe Keim, could you please guide me to the documentation? I have read the docs.. but Can't find an example. they are very unclear.. I tried with every option, and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio provides a user friendly way for deploying projects.

Choose **Build >> Publish (Your Project name)**

in Visual studio. If you are hosting on azure then it should be very simple. If its something else then you can choose "Custom" and follow instructions.